# Hibernate's BasicBinder binds DateTime to Timestamp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am facing strange issue...

I created a new project and moved a couple of code snippets from the old one. Installed new versions of hibernate (4.2.5) and spring (4.0.5). Now all the mysql's datetime fields are binded to timestamps objects with different format: instead of `2014-07-22 12:00:00` I receive  `Tue Jul 22 12:00:00 CEST 2014`... Mysql connector, db version and eclipse version are the same. Field describe in the following way:

```
@Column(name = "PickupDateTime")
private Date pickupDateTime;
```

where Date is `java.util.Date`.

What it can be? Thank you in advance

Comment: [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is a `java.util.Date`. Strictly speaking it doesn't require a conversion. If you want something different add a `@Temporal` annotation to specify what it needs to be. What you see is just a `toString()` of the object.

Answer (score 0):

For mapping `java.util.Date`, do this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date pickupDateTime;
```